# Dropdowns in the admin area appear underneath the modal window

Tags: wordpress, civimember

Dropdowns in the admin area appear underneath the modal window making it impossible to select a required dropdown, example: When I add new membership type I can't select Membership Organisation or Financial Type, see the screenshot: [image]

Comment: Are you able to reproduce this problem in the demo site? http://wpmaster.demo.civicrm.org/

Comment: It would be helpful if you could add the versions of CiviCRM and WordPress that you are using.

Comment: It is fine on the demo site. I'm on civiCRM 4.6 with Wordpress 4.3.2
The demo site is on Wordpress 4.4.2. Could it be that small version difference in Wordpress?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It was a conflict with css coming from another plugin (Slider Revolution). Its global.css has defined the following css property .ui-dialog { z-index: 1000102 !important; } which caused the behaviour described above.

Answer (score 1):

on functions.php add :

```
function my_custom_fonts() {
  echo '
     .select2-drop-active{ z-index: 99999999 !important;}
';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

One hack around this that works for us is:

1. Click the dropdown
2. Move drag the pop-up box to one side to see what the dropdown displays
3. Click the dropdown again to close it
4. Click the dropdown once more
5. Use the curser keys to select your dropdown option
6. Hit the Enter key on your keyboard to select the dropdown option.

Answer (score 0):

This is based on what user17092013 wrote above.

```
add_action('admin_head', 'my_custom_fonts');

function my_custom_fonts() {
  echo '
     .select2-drop-active { z-index: 99999999 !important; }
     ';
}
```