# civicrm dropdown list not appearing on the same popup but underneath pop-up's layer

Tags: wordpress, civicontribute

[image]i am having a strange issue . 
1.when i click on any drop-down , list does not show on the same place , but appears beneath  the pop-up/ or the dropdown's layer.
here is the  screen shot, what's wrong i am not able to figure out.

Comment: no screenshot supplied. have you tried using some other themes to see if that is your problem?

Comment: sorry for not uploading the screenshot .i de-activated the theme still the issue was appearant.

Comment: Could you please edit your question to show the screenshot?

Comment: i have attached the screen shot @JonG-MegaphoneTech

Comment: @petednz-fuzion, attached the screenshot

Answer (score 2):

We are having the same problem and its annoying as we can't added Shortcodes. Another post from 2016 found it was a CSS conflict with Slider Revolution.

[Dropdowns in the admin area appear underneath the modal window](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/9778/dropdowns-in-the-admin-area-appear-underneath-the-modal-window).

Using the Function snippet didn't fix the problem for us or changing the CSS.

One hack around this that works for us is:

1. Click the dropdown
2. Move drag the pop-up box to one side to see what the dropdown displays
3. Click the dropdown again to close it
4. Click the dropdown once more
5. Use the curser keys to select your dropdown option
6. Hit the Enter key on your keyboard to select the dropdown option.

Answer (score 0):

Do you possibly have a custom css stylesheet set up for Civi? I'd try inspecting the window to see if there is a style conflict.